# python, get list of values from list of JSON elements

Tags: python, json, list

I have a list of JSON elements that looks like this (but much longer)

```
[{u'account': u'', u'confirmations': 143236, u'amount': 5.61365738, u'address': u'8Zvt5usQB7dEEtyK7An3XFdqMSHgxTtZpz'}, {u'account': u'', u'confirmations': 2074, u'amount': 2.0, u'address': u'8K8GEVktJZQvrw5RtYzafD3qk3dAbNsTSQ'}]
```

Im trying to extract a list of all the `'amount'` into a list of floats, but I can oly get a single value, here is my code so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import json
import subprocess

json_data = json.loads(subprocess.check_output(['solarcoind', 'listreceivedbyaddress'], shell=False))

for a in json_data:
        amounts = (a ['amount'])

print amounts
```

My print only gives the last value, in this case `2.0`, how do I list all the amounts please?

Comment: I suppose step 1 would be... have a list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`amounts = [a['amount'] for a in json_data]`